# Golang, how can i get color value of a particular pixel on the screen in real time

Tags: image, go

I need to get the value of a single pixel of the screen at a predetermined location, in something like hex or rgb and it should be quite fast. How can i do that in Go?

Comment: Please share any code sample that you have tried.

Comment: @HamzaAnis sorry but im not even sure where to start, i looked up some image processing libraries but i cant seem to find what i need

Comment: To get pixels from the screen you need to ask the operating system. What OS are you targeting?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco im on linux

Comment: Linux does not (necessarily) have a screen in the first place (headless server, for instance). A machine with a display screen may have multiple displays and many windows. You're going to have to pin this down considerably further, in other words.

Comment: Yeah, there are probably various ways to do it in Linux depending on your display system (X, Wayland) and perhaps graphical shell (Gnome shell). I'd probably start by looking at one of the Linux color pickers and see how they do it: https://www.ubuntupit.com/best-color-picker-tools-for-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Rosetta Code has a page with solutions for this problem in various languages, including Go.
https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Color_of_a_screen_pixel

Using the [RobotGo](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-vgo/robotgo) library you can call [`GetPixelColor`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-vgo/robotgo#GetPixelColor) to get the color of a screen pixel as a hex string.

> RobotGo supports Mac, Windows, and Linux(X11); and robotgo supports arm64 and x86-amd64.